# -ingroup vs --ingroup

Tags: users, user-management, adduser

Instead of:

```
sudo adduser --ingroup hadoopgroup hadoopuser
```

I did a:

```
sudo adduser -ingroup hadoopgroup hadoopuser
```

am OK to go? Or the single `-` will cause a problematic user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`adduser` is a Perl script](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/wily/adduser/wily/view/head:/adduser#L35), using [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html). Unless explicitly told to do so, `Getopt::Long` will accept single-hyphen long options, and `adduser` doesn't tell it do so. So, `-ingroup` will work just as well as `--ingroup`.

Don't rely on this to work in the future, though.